# How do I use ES6 (ES2015) in a ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, transpiler

I have a 4.2 rails app and am considering slowly converting the JS to ES6. Right now I'm using the standard rails manifest file from the asset pipeline to pre-process my js.

I'm not sure how to go about starting to use ES6 (adding a transpile step) in my rails app.

Is there a built-in method, or a recommended tool or workflow?

Comment: A quick google search shows [this article](http://nandovieira.com/using-es2015-with-asset-pipeline-on-ruby-on-rails) that might be of use to you.

Comment: You want to use babel. This gem might do it for you. https://github.com/babel/ruby-babel-transpiler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering for myself 3 years later...

Rails > 5.1 has `webpacker` and native support for webpack builds and various front end frameworks if desired (react, vue, etc)

Comment: was  this approach more efficient in production

Comment: @ShireeshaParampalli yes!

Answer (score 19):

At present unfortunately there isn't really a 'standard' way of doing this - a lot of it depends on the requirements of your app and if you are able to upgrade Sprockets and/or Rails.

**Option 1:**
Stay on Rails 4.2 and Sprockets 3, then use this gem to add ES6 support and gradually migrate to ES6 modules: https://github.com/rmacklin/sprockets-bumble_d

**Option 2:**
Upgrade to Sprockets 4 (still in beta), then use either https://github.com/fnando/babel-schmooze-sprockets or https://github.com/babel/ruby-babel-transpiler to add babel for ES6 support. Both have pretty solid documentation.

**Option 3:**
Use webpack either instead of or alongside sprockets. A google search will reveal some approaches for this. Rails 5.1 (still in beta) will introduce native webpack (and thus babel) support via the [webpacker gem](https://github.com/rails/webpacker). Admittedly this may be the more difficult option for an existing application. There is a good article about it here: https://medium.com/statuscode/introducing-webpacker-7136d66cddfb#.cb4sixyah

Comment: "Ruby Babel Transpiler

Ruby Babel is a bridge to the JS Babel transpiler.

require 'babel/transpiler'
Babel::Transpiler.transform File.read("foo.es6")

Installation

$ gem install babel-transpiler

Dependencies

This library depends on the babel-source gem which is updated any time a new version of Babel is released.
ExecJS

The ExecJS library is used to automatically choose the best JavaScript engine for your platform. Check out its README for a complete list of supported engines."

Comment: I wouldn't say that something has "solid documentation" when its entire documentation page can fit in a StackOverflow comment, with room left to spare in the 600-character limit.

Comment: It tells you how to use it from Javascript, but not from Rails (Rails is not a Javascript backend, so the sample backend code in Javascript is pretty useless in the context of Rails).

Answer (score 2):

Replace this in your production.rb file

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

with this

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

For dev, Chrome compiles es6.

https://github.com/lautis/uglifier

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/uglifier

Comment: This just makes Uglifier support ES6 syntax - it does *not* transpile it.