# Why Rails doesn't transpile ES6 into ES5 with webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

After adding ES6 JavaScript into my Rails project:

```
class SpinnerWindow {
  static show() {
    //...
  }

  static autoHideShow(timeout=1500) {
    //...
  }

  static hide() {
    //...
  }
}
```

and deploying to Heroku it still contains compiled ES6 (not ES5!)

```
...</div>  </div></div>';class SpinnerWindow{static show(){...
```

i've added all need configurations into `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": "> 1%",
        "uglify": true
      },
      "useBuiltIns": true
    }]
  ],

  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoping",
    "transform-es2015-classes",
    "transform-es2015-computed-properties",
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    "transform-es2015-for-of",
    "transform-es2015-function-name",
    "transform-es2015-literals",
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
    "transform-es2015-object-super",
    "transform-es2015-parameters",
    "transform-es2015-shorthand-properties",
    "transform-es2015-spread",
    "transform-es2015-sticky-regex",
    "transform-es2015-template-literals",
    "transform-es2015-typeof-symbol",
    "transform-es2015-unicode-regex",
    "transform-regenerator",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }],
    // Reference assets directly from app/assets/**
    // https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/assets.md#using-babel-module-resolver
    ["module-resolver", { "root": ["./app"], "alias": { "assets": "./app/assets" } }]
  ]
}
```

Also i've added to `'production.rb'`:

```
  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

that's mentioned here
[How do I use ES6 (ES2015) in a ruby on rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460626/how-do-i-use-es6-es2015-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app)

Versions:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.10'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.6'
gem 'babel-transpiler'
```